# Path Tansition Binding

Tags: java, animation, binding, javafx

So I want to create a pendulum using path transition and binding. I tried to bind the end of the line to the center of the circle but when I do that the line doesn't move. I also tried another path transition for the line itself but then it would move from its center. I'm new to java so I don't know how to get past this.

```
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import com.sun.javafx.geom.Arc2D;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Pendulum extends Application{   

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setPrefSize(400,400);
    Arc arc = new Arc(200, 200, 105, 75, 0, -180);
    arc.setType(ArcType.OPEN);
    arc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    arc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    arc.setStrokeWidth(2);
    Circle cir = new Circle(200,275,10);
    cir.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    Line line = new Line(200,100,200,275);
    PathTransition pt = new PathTransition (Duration.millis(2000),arc,cir);
    pt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    pt.setAutoReverse(true);
    pt.play();
    line.endXProperty().bind(cir.centerXProperty());
    line.endYProperty().bind(cir.centerYProperty());
    root.getChildren().addAll(arc,cir,line);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`PathTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PathTransition.html) works by updating the `translateX` and `translateY` properties of the node that is being animated. Hence `centerX` and `centerY` never change. The following fix will work:

```
    line.endXProperty().bind(cir.centerXProperty().add(cir.translateXProperty()));
    line.endYProperty().bind(cir.centerYProperty().add(cir.translateYProperty()));
```